# Joomla 4 Helper class not found

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-4, joomla-4.1

I'm sure I've missed something obvious, but I'm stumped.

I have a helper class located at:
**administrator/components/com_supersite/src/Helper/supersite.php**

```
<?php

\defined('_JEXEC') or die();

class Supersite {
```

I'm using a system plugin to register it as:

```
<?php
\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;
use Joomla\CMS\Log\Log;

class PlgSystemSupersite extends CMSPlugin
{

    public function onAfterInitialise() {
        Log::add('running onAfterInitialise in supersite plugin');
        JLoader::registerPrefix('Supersite', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_supersite/src');
    }
}
```

And then I try to do a very basic call to the class, pulling a json string to array:

```
<?php

namespace Joomla\Component\Supersite\Site\Controller;

use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController;
use Supersite;

\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class ajaxController extends BaseController
{

    public function json()
    {
        $supersite = new Supersite();
        
        $prices = $supersite->getData('products/customer-price.json');
        echo json_decode($prices);
    }
}
```

And the resulting error message:

```
{"error":true,"code":0,"message":"Class \"Supersite\" not found","trace":"#0 C:\\Users\\username\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Development\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla\\libraries\\src\\MVC\\Controller\\BaseController.php(672): Joomla\\Component\\Supersite\\Site\\Controller\\ajaxController->json()\n#1 C:\\Users\\username\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Development\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla\\libraries\\src\\Dispatcher\\ComponentDispatcher.php(143): Joomla\\CMS\\MVC\\Controller\\BaseController->execute('json')\n#2 C:\\Users\\username\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Development\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla\\libraries\\src\\Component\\ComponentHelper.php(355): Joomla\\CMS\\Dispatcher\\ComponentDispatcher->dispatch()\n#3 C:\\Users\\username\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Development\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla\\libraries\\src\\Application\\SiteApplication.php(200): Joomla\\CMS\\Component\\ComponentHelper::renderComponent('com_supersite')\n#4 C:\\Users\\username\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Development\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla\\libraries\\src\\Application\\SiteApplication.php(241): Joomla\\CMS\\Application\\SiteApplication->dispatch()\n#5 C:\\Users\\username\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Development\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla\\libraries\\src\\Application\\CMSApplication.php(294): Joomla\\CMS\\Application\\SiteApplication->doExecute()\n#6 C:\\Users\\username\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Development\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla\\includes\\app.php(61): Joomla\\CMS\\Application\\CMSApplication->execute()\n#7 C:\\Users\\username\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Development\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla\\index.php(32): require_once('C:\\\\Users\\\\username\\\\...')\n#8 {main}"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Joomla4 and Namespaces therefore you no longer need to have a plugin to register the class, that should be available to the Autoloader in `/administrator/cache/autoload_psr4.php`.

The namespace for your component should not use the `Joomla\` prefix but one of your own, eg. `James\`.

In your manifest file, `supersite.xml`, you should have your namespace element set like this    `<namespace path="src">James\Component\Supersite</namespace>`

In your `administrator/components/com_supersite/src/Helper/supersite.php` it should have a Namespace of `James\Component\Supersite\Administrator\Helper`.

And your Controller class should be namespaced as `James\Component\Supersite\Site\Controller`.

If you are updating the files on your Joomla instance directly you will need delete the file `/administrator/cache/autoload_psr4.php` where it will be recreated automatically with a line near the top that looks like

```
'James\\Component\\Supersite\\Administrator\\' => [JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/Supersite/src'],
'James\\Component\\Supersite\\Site\\' => [JPATH_SITE . '/components/Supersite/src'],
```

If you have an API section of your component there will be a similar line created for it as well in the autoload file.If you are going through the Install process to bring in the above changes then it will/should automatically rebuild the autoload_psr4.php file for you and should not require being deleted.

In your Controller you need to replace `use Supersite;` with `use James\Component\Supersite\Administrator\Helper\Supersite`

If I have got it right that should get it working for you or at least a lot closer and without the use of the Plugin. The approach is sensitive to the case used in the Namespace and the files/folders they resolve to.

Comment: Great answer @Irata, thank you!